# Why Whould i need To use Javascript Object Prototype

Tags: javascript

I have been working with JavaScript for quite some time now , and I use objects a lot but am always wondering when is the time that I will need to use prototypes !! if I need a new method for an object I just go edit that object and add that method and in most cases I know what properties  and methods that I need when am creating the object.

what I sow beneficial in prototypes that I can make an object inherits from another one :

```
    var Person = function(firstname,lastname) {
        this.first_name = firstname;
        this.last_name = lastname;
    };

    var employee = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
    };

   employee.prototype = new Person();
```

when would I really need to use prototypes or what is the best cases to use prototypes ?

Regards,

Comment: This might be a good overview of some OOP design patterns in JavaScript: [Learning JavaScript Design Patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#designpatternsjavascript)

Answer (score 3):

Just two common use cases:

**1) Faster instance creation**

If your are using constructor functions to create objects, you could add methods directly in this constructor:

```
var Person = function(firstname,lastname) {
     this.first_name = firstname;
     this.last_name = lastname;
     this.sayName = function () {
         alert("Hi, my name is " + this.first_name + " " + this.last_name);
     };
};
```

This however, has the disadvantage, that the function will be created for every instance, which takes additional time. Adding the method to the prototype will speed up the creation of instances, since the function has to be defined only once:

```
var Person = function(firstname,lastname) {
     this.first_name = firstname;
     this.last_name = lastname;
};

Person.prototype.sayName = function () {
    alert("Hi, my name is " + this.first_name + " " + this.last_name);
};
```

**2) Extend Objects**

Use `prototype` to extend build-in (or custom) objects. Example:

```
Array.prototype.forEach = function (callback) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        callback(this[i], i);
    }
};

var arr = [1,2,3,4];
arr.forEach(function(item, index) {
    console.log(item);
});
```

This enables you also to override functions that were defined on the prototype and affect all created instances.

Answer (score 2):

> if I need a new method for an object I just go edit that object and
>   add that method and in most cases I know what properties and methods
>   that I need when am creating the object.

One benefit of using prototypes is that it allows for method sharing. If objects `A` and `B` have the same prototype, then adding function `C` to their prototype will allow both `A` and `B` to access that function.

This way, you don't need to be editing both your objects to add that new method. Hence, less code duplication and more memory efficient.